# How to partition a list and leave in the last sublist which is of different length?

Tags: list-manipulation

How to partition a list and leave in the last sublist which is of different length?

```
In[75]:= Partition[{1,2,3,4,5},2]
Out[75]= {{1,2},{3,4}}
```

I want it to be

```
{{1,2},{3,4},{5}}
```

Comment: This is easily answered by the documentation: `Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}]`

Comment: Em ... sorry that somehow my scan through the doc didn't catch this.

Comment: OK, so you don't mind if this is closed as Too Localized?

Comment: What do i do to questions i opened that i no longer need answer?  Should i press "delete" button myself?

Comment: @rm-rf @Sjoerd This is a very common problem though, and it has a somewhat unexpectedly inconvenient syntax.  One really has to read through the `Partition` docs fully to find it, otherwise it's not obvious that `Partition` can even do this.  I would not close or delete the question, but post the answer instead.

Comment: @Szabolcs (and MonkeyKing or anyone else with voting privilege) Ok, then please also throw in a vote to reopen and I'll post my comment as an answer with explanation (I'll vote to reopen with at least 2-3 votes on board).

Comment: @Szabolcs OK, voted to reopen.

Comment: See also [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7511/121) for some more elaborate partition schemes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the additional arguments of `Partition` to achieve this result. The first 5 arguments of `Partition` are (see the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) for more info):

- `list`: The list to be partitioned
- `n`: Length of the sublists (except perhaps for sublists with insufficient elements). Should be less than `Length@list`
- `d`: Partition offset. By default this is the same as `n` (no overlaps). A smaller value will result in overlaps of `n-d` samples and a larger value will result in skipping of `d-n` samples after every `n` samples.
- `{kL, kR}`: Determines whether overhangs are allowed at the beginning or the end of the list
- `x`: If overhangs are allowed, sublists with insufficient elements are padded with `x`.

Using the above, you can get your desired output with:

```
Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}} *)
```

Comment: I think it's simpler to use `Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2, 2, 1, {}]`

Comment: @Murta Yes, but I didn't think this was the question to mention non-pair values for the overhang parameter, especially since the OP didn't know what they were (btw, for the sake of completeness, they can take values other than ±1 too, as in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15466/5), although the docs don't mention it)

Comment: @rm-rf Do you know how to partition with the last two list combined? For example `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` to `{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}`, or `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` to `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7,8}}`. Thanks.

Comment: @xslittlegrass You can post-process the output with a rule. Something like `list /. {h___List, p_List, l_List} :> {h, p ~Join~ l}`

Comment: @rm-rf OK that works, thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

A useful `Manipulate` can help understanding how `Partition` works. It also provides the code to use for a certain partitioning.

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{
   {"original list:", Range[n]},
   {},
   {"without offset:", Partition[Range[n], part]},
   {"code:", Style[With[{n = n, part = part}, HoldForm@Partition[Range[n], part]], Bold]},
   {},
   {"with offset:", Partition[Range[n], part, offset, pos, pad]},
   {"code:", Style[With[{n = n, part = part, offset = offset, pos = pos, pad = pad}, 
      HoldForm@Partition[Range[n], part, offset, pos, pad]], Bold]}
   }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}}, Spacings -> {1, 1}],
 Item[Style["Understanding Partition", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 18]],
 Delimiter,
 {{n, 9, "length"}, 0, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{part, 1, "partition size"}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{offset, part, "offset"}, 1, part, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{pos, {1, 1}, "position"}, {{1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}, ControlType -> SetterBar},
 {{pad, "X", "padding with"}, {{} -> "{}", 0, 1, a, "X", Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 12]}, ControlType -> SetterBar}
 ]
```

[image: Understanding Partition]

Comment: Thank you very much for your pedagogical tool, very nice! I indeed understand partition via dragging those sliders : )